# How to detect mistakes of saving images in android wrong density directory?

Tags: android

In my android projects, I have found my mistakes that some images in *res/drawable-xhdpi* are larger than images of same name in *res/drawable-xxhdpi*.

Detecting these mistakes with just eyes is very difficult.

How to detect efficiently these mistakes?

Comment: There is no automate process to do it. So you have to make sure you are putting right resources in right directory.

Comment: I think only eyes will help you in this case.

Comment: You could perhaps use a command-line tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to create a script that checks the sizes for various inconsistencies.

Comment: Code your own & stick it on Play Store @ 99c a copy  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any automated tool to do this. If you are using android studio, you can switch to **Android Project View** which lists the images with same name in different density directories together. So it will be easy to compare the sizes.

[image]

And you can double click on each drawable to see it's size.

[image]

More info about Android Project View : https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html

Answer (score 0):

There is No direct method for it.

But with Android Studio you can do this easy steps :

1. Copy image from explorer or any other source with desired resolution
2. Right click on drawable folder in android studio.
3. Select Paste
4. It will popup you to select the desired folder
5. Select correct folder and click OK...